# Parse.Query.or internal error: does the query order matter?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have an array of queries which I unite with the OR operation, [Parse.Query.or](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Query.html#.or). Sometimes I get the following error.

> {"code":1,"error":"internal error"}

This error occurs at some requests, but not all, and I have come up with that the order of the queries affects the response (I added a shuffle method that randomly order the queries to come up with this). Logging the query order made me realize that some distinct orders makes the query execution fail and the rest works just as expected.

`queries` is of type `Parse.Query[]`.

```
queries = _.shuffle(queries);
var unionQuery = Parse.Query.or.apply(Parse.Query, queries);
unionQuery.find({ useMasterKey: true }).then(function (res) {
    console.log('success');
}).fail(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Does the [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) do something strange which will make my query fail sometimes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the line

```
var unionQuery = Parse.Query.or.apply(Parse.Query, queries);
```

with a loop that operates each query at a time, solved the problem.

```
var unionQuery = queries.pop();
_.each(queries, function (query) {
    unionQuery = Parse.Query.or(unionQuery, query);
});
```

However, I have no idea why this works in contrast to the original code using the apply method.

Comment: Really interesting.  It would be a nice add to the sdk for them to provide the array versions of all of the argument-list-accepting methods, and vice versa.